# Codeigniter 4 - Redirect inside routes.php

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I need to redirect '/home' URL to '/' in Codeigniter 4.

The code below does it perfectly, but I wonder if there is a better way to do this inside the Routes.php file.

```
$routes->get('/', 'Pages::view/home');
$routes->get('/home', function()
    {
        header('Location: '.'/');
    }
);
```

## ANSWER

```
$routes->get('/', 'Pages::view/home');
$routes->addRedirect('/home', '/');
```

Comment: Did you try this ? https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html#redirecting-routes I have never used it but seems like a fair option

Comment: @ViLar, how would that code be for my example? I read that but was not able to make it work.